# Why is my Rails server not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I try to start my Rails server, using the `rails server` command, I get many errors. How do I fix them?

```
/home/action/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse': (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 6 column 15 (Psych::SyntaxError)                                                          
    from /home/action/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:205:in `parse_stream'                                                                                                                                            
    from /home/action/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:153:in `parse'                                                                                                                                                   
    from /home/action/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/2.0.0/psych.rb:129:in `load'                                                                                                                                                    
    from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@learn-rails/gems/figaro-0.7.0/lib/figaro.rb:21:in `raw'                                                                                                                                    
    from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@learn-rails/gems/figaro-0.7.0/lib/figaro.rb:17:in `env'                                                                                                                                    
    from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@learn-rails/gems/figaro-0.7.0/lib/figaro/railtie.rb:7:in `block in <class:Railtie>'                                                                                                        
    from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `call'                                                                                                    
    from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'                                                                                            
    from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'                                                                                 
    from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'                                                                                                    
    from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@learn-rails/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'                                                                                          
    from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:67:in `inherited'                                                                                                                 
    from /home/action/workspace/learn-rails/config/application.rb:10:in `<module:LearnRails>'                                                                                                                                              
    from /home/action/workspace/learn-rails/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'                                                                                                                                                  
    from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `require'                                                                                                                      
    from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `block in <top (required)>'                                                                                                    
    from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'                                                                                                                          
    from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@learn-rails/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'                                                                                                             
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Here is application.rb file code:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

module LearnRails
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de
  end
end
```

**LAST EDIT**

Thank you, it was weird problem with application.yml file! Now it works like a charm!

Comment: Likely a syntax error in some yaml config?

Comment: It tells you exactly where to look: /home/action/workspace/learn-rails/config/application.rb:10:in `<module:LearnRails>' Post this file if you don't know where to look.

Comment: Please post your application.rb file, as that's _probably_ where the problem lies (specifically lines 9 or 10).

Comment: As @MikeK told, there might be some syntax error in one of the yaml config files. Check the yml files in the config folder (most likely databas.yml file). even extra spaces can cause error.

Comment: In my case, it was a syntax error in application.yml.
I was using "=" instead of ":" to assign values

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an error with figaro gem. the `Psych::SyntaxError` suggests your `application.yml` file may be the problem.

Comment: It's not necessary to say "[edit] it seems you have already solved the issue. Ignore this". Either delete the question, or let it stay. Telling people to ignore it after they've already read it does no good.